# Unable to boot into Windows after Ubuntu 14.04.3 installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows

After installing and restarting my laptop I keep getting booted into Ubuntu and can't find any method for using a bootloader.

Comment: Open a terminal (`ctrl` + `alt` + `T`) and run `sudo update-grub`. Reboot and see if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Disable GRUB hidden timeout.

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu  

gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Place a `#` in front of `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

So that it reads now: `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

Save the change - close the file and ... execute:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now you should see the GRUB boot loader on start.

There should be a Windows entry in the boot menu.