# Unable to boot into Windows after installation of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, windows, boot-repair

I'm using an HP laptop with Windows/Ubuntu 18.04, but after a reinstallation of Ubuntu, I can't boot into Windows. Advanced options for Ubuntu and system settings, but I can't find the option for accessing Windows.

I don't really know what the problem is. I tried a lot of suggestions here, but none worked.

1. I tried the accepted answer in this question ([Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)), after creating a file and rebooting. I could see an option called Windows-UEFI. But if I try to click on that and proceed I get the error,

   ```
   error : no such device : /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi.
   error : file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found.
   ```
2. Then I tried running the Boot Info Script (http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/). The output is uploaded here: https://file.io/vuch51vB.

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /tmp/BootInfo-QDw4MMPm/sda2: unknown filesystem type ''.

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 1,953,525,167 1,953,525,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048       534,527       532,480 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2         534,528       567,295        32,768 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda3         567,296   371,412,991   370,845,696 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda4   1,917,038,592 1,919,045,631     2,007,040 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda5   1,919,045,632 1,953,511,423    34,465,792 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda6     371,412,992   694,374,399   322,961,408 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sda8     694,374,400 1,917,038,591 1,222,664,192 Data partition (Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop1                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop10                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop11                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop12                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop13                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop14                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop15                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop16                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop17                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop18                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop19                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop2                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop20                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop21                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop22                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop23                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop24                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop25                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop3                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop4                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop5                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop6                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop7                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop8                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop9                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        E52D-D92B                              vfat       
/dev/sda2                                                          
/dev/sda3        4410959410958E14                       ntfs       Windows
/dev/sda4        6C6CDA8F6CDA5384                       ntfs       Windows RE tools
/dev/sda5        009052CF9052CAB4                       ntfs       RECOVERY
/dev/sda6        921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1   ext4       
/dev/sda8        4f953876-2a36-48ef-9ee9-47206f509d05   ext4       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /boot/efi                vfat       (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda6        /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda8        /home                    ext4       (rw,noatime)


=========================== sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-59-generic root=UUID=921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-59-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-59-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-59-generic-advanced-921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.0-59-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-59-generic root=UUID=921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-59-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-59-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-59-generic-recovery-921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.0-59-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-59-generic root=UUID=921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-59-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-53-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-53-generic-advanced-921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.0-53-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=UUID=921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-53-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-53-generic-recovery-921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.0-53-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=UUID=921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda6/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=921eabcd-626b-4ecc-bd47-40ea213357f1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=E52D-D92B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
# /home is on /dev/sda8, edited after install
UUID=4f953876-2a36-48ef-9ee9-47206f509d05   /home   ext4    noatime 0   2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda6: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-QDw4MMPm/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```

3. I tried editing the grub-file as mentioned here ([Unable to boot into Windows after Ubuntu 14.04.3 installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723598/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-ubuntu-14-04-3-installation))

It did not work either.

At this point, I don't know what exactly my problem is. also I'm scared of messing up the whole system if I try new solutions without knowing what I'm doing. Can anyone help me to find out the problem?

Comment: Do you acutally have a file /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi that cannot be found (you need sudo to browse boot/efi)? And since it is an HP laptop, you may have a 'boot from efi file' option that lets you browse the EFI partition for a suitable boot file.

Comment: For me it looks like you have simply installed Windows as Legacy BIOS and Ubuntu as UEFI. Do you remember whether you could see "Install Alingside Windows" option when installing Ubuntu? Please reply with @ for example @brownfox

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I don't really remember. Is there any way to check it now?

Comment: @brownfox You can check in your firmware settings. Check what the boot mode is. It should be something like Legacy and UEFI. Also check whether Windows and Ubuntu are in the same boot mode

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a UEFI install of both Window and Ubuntu

1. Check `efibootmgr -v`

This will ***verbosely*** produce something like this:

```
efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 60 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,001D,000B,000C,000E,000D,001B,001C,001E
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,63c4ca60-c3b9-45a4-979a-f25f25c3d28e,0x1f4800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot0002  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,63c4ca60-c3b9-45a4-979a-f25f25c3d28e,0x1f4800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0005  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0006  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0007  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0008  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot000B* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot000C* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot000D* ATAPI CD1 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,aea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a35404)
Boot000E* ATA HDD0  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f600)
Boot001B* ATA HDD1  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f602)
Boot001C* ATA HDD2  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f603)
Boot001D* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot001E* PCI LAN   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
```

My complicated setup has the advantage of booting from several entries, but as I can see **NO** evidence of `bootmgfw.efi` (I suggest you try `find / -name '*.efi'`) , I presume you have thoroughly checked all your file systems for errors.

Failing success, using information from your  efibootmgr`try in my case as an example:

`efibootmgr -n 000E`

In the above this will produce a one time boot attempt by looking for the entry `000E`in the list. Which yields **BOOT000E ATA HDD0** in my case, in yours you need to find the entries corresponding to sda3-6[given they contain Windows  components], and try each.

These entries are added by UEFI (in BIOS) boot selection order, and are not normally removed, but re-ordered.

**EDIT 1:** `sda1` Contains what looks like a normal EFI boot structure but `sda6` contains Both /boot and /BCD (the windows registry) Use the above `find` , combined with your `efibootmgr` output, which should indicate where your Windows boot structure/disk is found or can be rebuilt from.

Typing `efibootmgr`**without '-v'**_ yields a simpler , less informative structure:

```
efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,001D,000B,000C,000E,000D,001B,001C,001E
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001  Startup Interrupt Menu
Boot0002  Rescue and Recovery
Boot0003* ubuntu
Boot0005  Setup
Boot0006  Boot Menu
Boot0007  Diagnostic Splash Screen
Boot0008  Lenovo Diagnostics
Boot000B* USB CD
Boot000C* USB FDD
Boot000D* ATAPI CD1
Boot000E* ATA HDD0
Boot001B* ATA HDD1
Boot001C* ATA HDD2
Boot001D* USB HDD
Boot001E* PCI LAN
```

**EDIT 2:**

If the file systems `sda1-7` are not mounted in order to run the above `find..` command, successively try `mkdir /tmp/sda1`, `mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/sda1` and `find /tmp/sda1 -name '*.efi'`, replacing sda1 for each partition.

As the previous threads have indicated,the goal is to find the correct ***.efi***

**EDIT 3 Best solution:**

After reading the first links you provided, I ran the `bootinfoscript`on my m/c, guess what? It doesn't look for the `bootmgfw.efi`**at all!**

The best suggestion provided by @Jordan Uggla in [unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix) provides the solution:

Your /dev/sda1 partition must contain  the Windows bootmgfw.efi as it is the defacto EFI partition, so based on @Jordan Uggla 's work , I edited it to:

```
Create a file, /boot/grub/custom.cfg (by running sudo -H gedit /boot/grub/custom.cfg) with these contents:

#This entry should work for any version of Windows installed for UEFI booting

menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-E52D-D92B' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-
efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1 E52D-D92B
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root E52D-D92B
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

(Copy and paste the above into the Gedit window that comes up, then save and quit Gedit)

Reboot and you should see an entry titled **`Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)`** and if you select it then Windows should boot, do look for the `bootmgfw.efi`in `/boot` , try `ls -R /boot|more` I'm sure it's in there!

Comment: I'm sorry. Did you write this with machine translation? I do not completely understand what you mean.

Comment: @brownfox [see efibootmgr man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/efibootmgr.8.html) `efibootmgr` defines the boot sequence, defaults  and parameters.In this case ,changing the sequence by __`efibootmgr -n XXXX`__ will force a boot which points to the hex XXXX in the `efibootmgr` list if it exists. Say XXXX points to `sda5`i. Upon reboot , boot will be forced to try XXXX (one time only).